# What should I use to seal this window?

Tags: windows

My master bedroom has a set of French doors with a window above the doors. During a recent thunderstorm, I noticed the window was rattling. Upon further inspection, the window is held in with little strips of wood at the top, left and right, but not the bottom. there is also nothing sealing the gap between the glass and the frame/wood.

I'm going to remove the strips and the glass this weekend and reinstall it properly. My question is: what type of product should I use to seal the glass in the frame?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You'll want to use glazing compound, which comes in both oil-based, and latex, and can be found in both cans or tubes.

Once you have the glass removed, and the frame cleaned up.

- Run a bead of glazing compound around the frame (where the glass will sit).
- Set the glass in the compound giving it a little wiggle to work out any air bubbles, and to make sure the glass is set in properly (don't worry about a little excess oozing out, you can trim it off later when it cures).
- Using a putty knife push in glazing points every 6-8 in.

[image: Glazing point]

- Install the interior trim, and wait for the glazing compound to cure.
- Once the compound has cured enough (24-72 hours), using a utility knife carefully trim off any compound that has oozed out.
- If you are not using interior trim, you will want to apply a bead of glazing compound to the interior side of the frame, and use a putty knife to smooth it to a nice finish.
- After 7-10 days you can paint the glazing compound to match the frame.

Comment: the removable trim is actually on the OUTSIDE of the window. does that make a difference?

Comment: @longneck - Yes. in that case you will want to finish the outside with glazing compound, smoothing it at a 45 degree angle with a putty knife.  You want to make sure water will not sit on the lip of the frame, so make sure the glazing compound bonds well to the glass and is angled to allow water to drain away.

Comment: great answer, sounds like you have done some glazing.....I hate glazing....LOL  +++

Comment: @shirlock - does anybody like glazing?

Comment: Just finished re-glazing three windows in their entirety.  It is not fun.  I would advise getting as good a glazing compound as you can find.  I used what I could find at Lowes, but it stuck to my fingers far better than it wanted to stick to the glass or the frame...

Answer (score 1):

You should use putty to bed the glass into the frame.

This will form an air- and water-tight seal.

You could even put the wood strips back on.